# Convex optimization with larger feasible set has more solutions, is this correct?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Let $f:A\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ be a convex function with convex set $A$. Let $B\subset A$ be a convex subset. Denote
\begin{equation}
S_{A}:=\arg\min\limits_{x\in A}f(x),\quad S_{B}:=\arg\min\limits_{x\in B}f(x).
\end{equation}
I guess $|S_{A}|\geq |S_{B}|$, where $|\cdot|$ denote cardinality of a set. Is my proposition correct? Can anyone help me prove it or give some counter example?

Comment: Interestingly, the statement is true for $A \subset \mathbb R^1$ but fails in higher dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x_1, x_2) = x_1$.

With $B = \{(x_1, x_2) : x_1 \ge 0, x_2 \in [-1, 1]\}$, the minimizers of $f$ are $\{(0, x_2) : x_2 \in [-1, 1]\}$.

However for $A = \{(x_1, x_2) : |x_2| \le x_1 + 1\}$, $f$ has a unique minimizer at $(-1, 0)$.